# Deploying spring boot executable jar on jboss but not as a war ,so that other applications can invoke as an api

Tags: spring-boot

I want to deploy an executable jar file on to jboss server, so that other application written in c/c++ can invoke it through workflow by passing the arguments to the executable jar file.
I have googled and found examples where war is deployed by making it restful webservice, but I could not find any such example where an executable jar file is deployed on jboss.

Appreciate your help

Regards,
Kiran Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You can not deploy the spring boot executable jar file in Jboss. You need tweak your application to some extent for it to work on JBoss.
1. Add jboss-web.xml file src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder, provide application context there.

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>YOUR_APP_ROOT</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Set below spring property in your yml/props file.

```
server.servlet-path = /*
```